# Is imperative Quicksort in situ (in-place) or not?

Tags: algorithm, terminology, complexity-theory, quicksort, space-complexity

Quicksort is often described as an *in situ* (in-place) algorithm, despite the fact that it requires O(log n) stack space. So does *in situ* mean "requires less than O(n) additional space", or does stack space generally not count as space complexity (but why would that be the case?), or is Quicksort actually not an *in situ* algorithm?

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/9563/6586. Basically, it is rather a flame bait with lots of contradictory arguments.

Comment: Note that this really depends on how you want *in-situ* to be defined. IF you are just comparing sorting algorithms it would be very nitpicky to not consider quicksort to be inplace but if you have a more formal definition in mind (hopefully with a reason) then it makes sense to stop ignoring the little O(log n) detail.

Comment: This is just a special case of "O(log n) might as well be a largeish constant", isn't it? In principle Quicksort uses O(log n) additional space. In practice you generally implement it to take something like an array as a parameter. Arrays in most languages have a natural upper size limit based on the fixed-width type used for address and/or indices, and Quicksort only needs to store a couple of addresses at each of `log n` depths. So stack use is constant-bounded for almost any implementation of Quicksort you'd ever actually write and use, even though it isn't for the "ideal" version.

Comment: ... so all that remains is an argument about the appropriate definition of "in situ" - the properties of Quicksort are straightforward, but for example C's `qsort` has the property that any decent implementation of it has a fixed maximum stack use.

Comment: @Jason: Of course there is controversy, since definitions only have a meaning as far as they are useful. I think it is perfectly acceptable to consider quick-sort to be in-situ if all you are doing is comparing it with things like mergesort. The only reason one should go as far as giving a precise O(1) definition to in-situ is if you are defining a complexity class or doing something similarly formal.

Comment: @Jesse What exactly do you mean by "fixed maximum stack use", O(1)?

Comment: Interestingly enough `in situ` rhymes with Nico Lomuto's last name who invented [in-place partitioning scheme for quick sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> is Quicksort actually not an in situ algorithm?

The standard implementation of it is **not** *in situ*. It's a horribly common misconception, but you as correctly note due to stack space consumption, that conception is wrong.

I say "standard implementation" of it because people have modified the algorithm to make it an `O(1)`-space algorithm. Here is one example: [Quicksort without a stack](http://books.google.com/books?id=oaVq6dbw37kC&pg=PA283&dq=Quicksort+in+constant+space&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VUMpT6zTJ8mEtgeB6ej9BA&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Quicksort%20in%20constant%20space&f=false).

Of course, consistent with the classic [space-time tradeoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff), such versions of quicksort are less performant than the standard implementation.

Answer (score 9):

Wikipedia offers the following [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm):

> In computer science, an in-place algorithm (or in Latin *in situ*) is an algorithm which transforms input using a data structure with a small, constant amount of extra storage space.

By this definition, the typical stack-based quicksort is clearly not an *in situ* algorithm.

In fact, the Wikipedia article explicitly discusses this:

> An algorithm is sometimes informally called in-place as long as it overwrites its input with its output. In reality this is not sufficient (**as the case of quicksort demonstrates)** nor is it necessary; the output space may be constant, or may not even be counted, for example if the output is to a stream.

and

> Quicksort is commonly described as an in-place algorithm, but is not in fact one. Most implementations require O(log n) space to support its divide and conquer recursion.

However, as pointed out by @Jason in his excellent answer, there appear to exist variants of quicksort that only require O(1) extra space. Any such alorithms would be considered *in situ*.